# Pilot light issue

Tags: hvac, light, boiler

Thermocouple has been changed but pilot still wont stay lit.
Is it gas controller?nSo what now?   I may also have a cracked heat exchanger but that would seem unrelated. A small amount ofwater underneath boiler casing . Raypak

Comment: we probably need the model number

Comment: A photo of the pilot in the flame, model number or where the water came from that you thought  to mention may all be important, if the water came out of the gas line you have bigger problems than we can help with here!